I want to clone Google Cloud Platform Cloud SQL between two different projects but got error 403 "The caller does not have permission"
Here below is my terraform source code
provider "google" {
  project = var.preprod_id
  region  = var.reqion
}

provider "google" {
  alias   = "source"
  project = var.prod_id
  region  = var.reqion
}

data "google_sql_database_instance" "source" {
    provider = google.source
    name = "plan-flow-db"
}
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "clone" {
  provider         = google
  name             = "cloned-plan-flow-db"  
  region           = var.reqion
  database_version = data.google_sql_database_instance.source.database_version

  clone {
    source_instance_name = data.google_sql_database_instance.source.name
  }

}

I use IAM and with configuration like this below
preprod

owner
cloud sql admin
cloud sql viewer
cloud sql client

prod

owner
cloud sql admin
cloud sql viewer
cloud sql client

however I stuck at this error
╷
│ Error: Error, failed to create instance cloned-plan-flow-db: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden
│ 
│   with google_sql_database_instance.clone,
│   on main.tf line 16, in resource "google_sql_database_instance" "clone":
│   16: resource "google_sql_database_instance" "clone" {
│ 
╵

anyone have ever solve this problem?

I suggest double-checking the permissions for your target project.
roles/cloudsql.editor (or roles/cloudsql.admin): Confirm this role is assigned to your service account in the target project (preprod_id). This role is crucial for creating new Cloud SQL instances.
If you are sure this is done correctly, review whether you have VPC access controls and grant necessary access within the perimeter.
You can review the permissions of a project:
gcloud projects get-iam-policy $preprod_id --flatten="bindings[].members" 
--format='table(bindings.role:sort=1, bindings.members)'

I try your solution by putting cloudsql.editor on both of my IAM project, it still got me error 403
